# Confirmation mailers - how to avoid code duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got two different process in my app after which I want to send to user a confirmation email after each process is finished. I could create two separate mailers eg. `BankProcessMailer` and `ShopProcessMailer` but they would contain the same code like below:

```
class BankProcess < BaseMailer
  layout 'bank_process'

  def send_email(email)
    mail_headers = headers(email)
    mail(mail_headers)
  end

  private

  def headers(email)
    super(email).merge(subject: 'Bank process')
  end
end
```

Is there any chance to handle one mailer with two different views and subjects to avoid code duplication and don't create new mailer for `ShopProcessMailer` like below ?

```
class ShopProcess < BaseMailer
  layout 'shop_process'

  def send_email(email)
    mail_headers = headers(email)
    mail(mail_headers)
  end

  private

  def headers(email)
    super(email).merge(subject: 'Shop process')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If what changes are only the `subject` and layout, you can create a class that inherits from BaseMailer, which is then used to inherit `ShopProcess` and  `BankProcess` from, then you can try something like this:

```
class ConfirmationMailer < BaseMailer
  protected

  def send_email(email)
    mail_headers = headers(email)
    mail(mail_headers)
  end

  def headers(email)
    super(email).merge(subject: SUBJECT)
  end
end

# frozen_string_literal: true

class BankProcess < ConfirmationMailer
  SUBJECT = 'Bank process'
  layout 'bank_process'
end

# frozen_string_literal: true

class ShopProcess < ConfirmationMailer
  SUBJECT = 'Shop process'
  layout 'shop_process'
end
```

Comment: Yes, you will. There's no reason to make one class more complex just because you want to save some lines of code. One class (as well as others) should do only one thing, and do it well. One class that does more than one thing must be separated and their functionalities distributed.